# How to update latest quantity when user buy a product? The database have not reduced the quantity

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
protected void btnBuyNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["USERID"].ToString());
    int PID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["PID"]);

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_UpdateProducts", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            int myQty = row.Field<int>("Qty");
            int PQuantity = row.Field<int>("PQuantity");

            if (myQty < PQuantity)
            {
                int updateQty = row.Field<int>("Qty");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", PQuantity - updateQty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", PID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Open();
                Response.Redirect("OrderConfirmation.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`SP_UpdateProducts`:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UpdateProducts]
    (@PID int,
     @Quantity int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE tblProducts 
    SET PQuantity = @Quantity 
    WHERE PID = @PID
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: What is your actual question? Please provide a [mre] i.e. sample data, expected results and actual results.

Comment: Learn to debug your own code. When you create the `@Quantity` parameter what value is assigned? And what value does updateQty contain? I don't see any declaration of that variable either. Lastly you seem to have a application problem when `if (myQty < PQuantity)` returns false - your app does nothing? WHERE is your error handling? Seems you have much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Updated] SqlDataAdapter supports for Insert, Update and Delete command as written in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2). For current scenario, you don't have to use SqlDataAdapter.
2. Before performing `ExceuteNonQuery()`, you need to ensure the connection is opened.
3. `updateQty` is weird, you get the quantity from database. Not sure what you try to achieve.
4. [Stop using `.AddWithValue()`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
5. Credited to @marc_s, you should not name the stored procedure with prefix "sp_"
6. For your Stored Procedure, you need to alter script to get the current `PQuantity` and minus with passed-in `Quantity`

Back-end (.aspx.cs) code:

```
protected void btnBuyNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Int32 UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["USERID"].ToString());
    int PID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["PID"]);
    int qty = /* Expected qty to be deducted in product */
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateProducts", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.int).Value = updateQty;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PID", SqlDbType.int).Value = PID;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("OrderConfirmation.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateProducts]
    (@PID int,
     @Quantity int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE tblProducts 
    SET PQuantity = PQuantity - @Quantity 
    WHERE PID = @PID
END
```

Comment: I agree OP doesn't need the data adapter, but they are made for modifying data as well as selecting data so I would not be telling people they are just for querying.

Comment: Hi @Crowcoder, thanks for the feedback. Checked from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) that `SqlDataAdapter` support for Insert, Update & Delete as well. I would update my answer as giving misinformation.

Comment: in my tblProducts, there is no Quantity, only PQuantity. Is that still possible that I can subtract the quantity as stated above in stored procedure?

Comment: `@Quantity` is input parameter, you pass the quantity to be deducted via this parameter for doing calculation: PQuantity (existing product quantity) - @Quantity (quantity has been sold) = PQuantity (latest available product quantity)

Comment: Second method is you query the product records with its current quantity. And move the calculation logic in your back end, and lastly update the product record with `PQuantity = @Quantity`. With this way, your Stored Procedure can be used for update quantity after purchase and also restock.

Comment: if I want to subtract from quantity in Cart table, is it possible? Means quantity from tblProducts subtract from quantity in tblCart. So we need to use 2 tables. How?

Comment: Hi @user15359738, you can try to query out the tblCart with the productID & quantity based on current order which was done for payment and then update the tblProduct for quantity. The logic can be implemented either in back end or Stored Proc.

Comment: Anyway, due to lack of information on your table schema and also business logic, I cannot give you precise ideas and comments. You may review and implement your business logic & its implementation structure first. If you face any difficulties, don't hesitate to ask in StackOverflow. Thank you.